# Unity: Set alpha via code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing an android game where I want to fade in the enemy as they spawn, The enemies are using standard (Specular shader), rendering mode is set it Fade ,prefabs have 0 alpha in albedo .To do this i use the following code

**Enemy fadeIn**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySetAlpha : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color enemyMesh;
    public float fadetime = 255;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        enemyMesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ().material.color;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
            fadeIn (fadetime);
    }

    void fadeIn(float time)
    {
        enemyMesh = new Color (1, 1, 1, 0 + (fadetime*Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the the enemy that script increases the alpha but the albedo alpha is still 0 thus not fading in the enemy.

Comment: Give it a shot to: `enemyMesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ().material; enemyMesh.SetColor(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Color` is a struct (value type), not a class (reference type), changing your private color `enemyMesh` won't change the color of the material. `enemyMesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ().material.color;` makes **a copy** of the color of the material. A complete new entity.

You have to reference the material (which is a reference type) and change its color:

```
public class EnemySetAlpha : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material enemyMaterial;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.1f;
    // Value used to know when the enemy has been spawned
    private float spawnTime ;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Because `Material` is a class,
        // The following line does not create a copy of the material
        // But creates a reference (points to) the material of the renderer
        enemyMaterial = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ().material;
        spawnTime = Time.time ;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
            // Set the alpha according to the current time and the time the object has spawned
            SetAlpha( (Time.time - spawnTime) * fadeSpeed );
    }

    void SetAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        // Here you assign a color to the referenced material,
        // changing the color of your renderer
        Color color = enemyMaterial.color;
        color.a = Mathf.Clamp( alpha, 0, 1 );
        enemyMaterial.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u this works, but how can a gradually increment fadetime to set alpha to 1, can you show it in your answer ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can change the alpha value over time.

Comment: This won't work as intended because `Time.time` returns overall time the game is running. So basically, this will set an alpha color greater than 1 whenever the game is running more than 10 seconds...

Comment: @m.rogalski : A simple Clamp and the problem is gone ;)

Comment: @Hellium no, it is not. Assume OP will spawn enemy after 1 minute when the game was launched. Using your code enemy will spawn completely faded, opaque. It won't gradually fade out.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After your object is loaded you have to modify ( not just replace ) the alpha value by adding another "step" value.

Basically, what you need is this piece of code :

```
void setAlpha()
{
    Color c = material.color;
    float current = c.a;
    current = Mathf.Min(current + fadetime * Time.deltaTime, 1.0f);
    c.a = current;
    material.color = c;
}
```

Then in your `Update` call you can just make one simple check:

```
if(material.color.a < 1.0f)
{
    setAlpha();
}
```